# synchronized block is not working quite right

Tags: java, multithreading, block, synchronized

i am unable to get synchronized blocks in java

i read this following post but didn't quite get about syn-blocks and locks

[Synchronized block not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029698/java-synchronized-block-not-working)

i don't know why below code is not outputting uniform array of A's,B's,C's
even after i synchronized it..

```
    public class synchronizeblock
{
    static StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer();
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Threading t1=new Threading(s,'a');
        Threading t2=new Threading(s,'b');
        Threading t3=new Threading(s,'c');
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();     
    }
}
class Threading extends Thread
{
    StringBuffer sb; 
    char ch;

    Threading()
    {

    }
    Threading(StringBuffer sb,char ch)
    {
        this.sb=sb;
        this.ch=ch;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(this)   // this(current instance) acts as lock ??
        {
                for(int i=0;i<20;++i)
                {
                    System.out.print(ch);
                }
        }       
    }

}
```

one of cases of output is as below:

> bbbbbbbbbbbbbaccccccccccccccccccccaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbb

my concern is that once a thread is started ,say thread with character 'b' (be it thread-"one")shouldn't it be completed before another thread gets chance to run because thread "one" got lock on the object,correct me if am wrong
and i have following questions

1. it's really confusing "what gets locked" and "what acts as lock".  So explain what exactly got locked in my code
2. and what should i do to get uniform output (by saying uniform output here ,i mean that once a thread starts its character should get printed 20 times)

Comment: `synchronized` takes a lock on the given object, `this` is this case. You have 3 different `Threading` instances, so they lock 3 different objects, and since nothing else tries to lock those objects, the locks have no effect.

Comment: When you say "got lock on the object", what object do you mean?

Comment: @Andreas so consider synchronized(aaaa) so aaaa does't act as lock, rather it gets locked,correct me if am wrong....

Comment: @DavidSchwartz current instance

Comment: @viru The phrasing used in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19) is: *"The executing thread locks the **monitor associated with** `aaaa`."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all `StringBuffer` are

> String buffers are safe for use by multiple threads. The
>   methods  are synchronized where necessary so that all the operations
>   on any particular instance behave as if they occur in some serial
>   order that is consistent with the order of the method calls made by
>   each of the individual threads involved.

and the rest you can read in bottom of your question but problem about not print my output like this `A's B's C's` its that your `Thread`s run even if the current thread not *finish* for that can use `join()` method its tell's the other thread wait until my job its finish then go do your job so, your `main` methods look like this

```
      Threading t1 = new Threading(s,'a');
      Threading t2 = new Threading(s,'b');
      Threading t3 = new Threading(s,'c');
      t1.start();
      t1.join();
      t2.start();
      t2.join();
      t3.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sb` for synchronizing because otherwise you do not synchronize with the other threads (you are locking the object for itself). Or create a locking object which is used for synchronizing between the three different objects.

```
public class Threading extends Thread
{
    private Object synchronizationContext;
    private StringBuffer sb; 
    private char ch;

    Threading(StringBuffer sb,char ch, Object synchronizationContext)
    {
        this.sb=sb;
        this.ch=ch;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(synchronizationContext)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<20;++i)
            {
                System.out.print(ch);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

and `main` use the same `synchronizationContext` for all.

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
    Object synchronizationContext = new Object();
    Threading t1 = new Threading(s,'a', synchronizationContext);
    Threading t2 = new Threading(s,'b', synchronizationContext);
    Threading t3 = new Threading(s,'c', synchronizationContext);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. it's really confusing "what gets locked" and "what acts as lock"

Not sure what you are asking.  When we do a `synchronized (obj)` then the `obj` is what is being locked.  The threads do the locking which may block if another thread already holds the lock.  It's not proper to say that the `obj` "acts as a lock".

> ```
> synchronized(this)   // this(current instance) acts as lock ??
> ```

You are locking on `this` which is the problem, see below.

> 2.and what should i do to get uniform output (by saying uniform output here

In your case, the problem is that you a synchronizing on `this`.  Each thread is locking on a *different* object.  If you want them to have a mutex lock to have exclusive access to printing their characters, then you will need to pass in a *common* object that they all lock on:

```
final Object lock = new Object();
Threading t1 = new Threading(lock,'a');
Threading t2 = new Threading(lock, b');
Threading t3 = new Threading(lock,'c');
...
class Threading extends Thread {
    final Object lock;
    final char ch;
    public Threading(Object lock, char ch) {
       this.lock = lock;
       this.ch = ch;
    }
    public void run() {
        // lock on a common lock object in all 3 threads
        synchronized (lock) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                System.out.print(ch);
            }
        }
    }
}
```